# American Accent

Tags: pronunciation

I’m an English teacher in Afghanistan; I personally speak with **neutral English accent**. While I was teaching speaking yesterday in my class, one of my students asked me:
How can I do a pure General American accent?

So, I’ve been wondering if there’re any mythologies and strategies (or techniques) to teach my students so as to do a **General American Accent**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Watch shows and movies and sing. By the way, when you say pure General American accent, there's no consensus on what General American Accent is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American

Comment: @Zebrafish thanks a lot, Zebrafish. However, aren’t there step by step techniques and/or strategies?

Comment: @EzatullahAmirAfghan the US covers an area of over 9 million square kilometres, the Middle East covers about 7 million square kilometres. The Middle East has about 60 different languages, and the one major language (Arabic) is spoken in different accents in different countries / parts of the Middle East. The same goes for the US, people in Montana speak differently from New Yorkers. Your best bet would be to focus on one particular accent (for example a New  York accent). Just search YouTube for: _New York accent_ and you will find great tips on how to talk like a New Yorker.

Comment: The New York accent isn't what most people would consider a General American accent. People who have one often try to lose it, especially if they are looking to succeed outside the NY area, as my father did. On the contrary, search YouTube for "general American accent".

Comment: I am not sure there is such thing as **"neutral English accent."** Also this question fits ELL better. There has been similar questions on English pedagogy on ELL recently with detailed answers.